# TypeScript definition file for SPServices

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, typescript, spservices, definitelytyped

I am wondering if anyone knows if there is a TypeScript definition file for the SPServices JS library? I have found a `.d.ts` file in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices/blob/master/src/jquery.SPServices.d.ts) but it does not appear to be complete. I have also search (with no luck except [this definition request](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4008)) through what is available on Definitely Typed. If none exists, does anyone know of a good reference for information about how to create definitions from the JS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find the definition you need. However, you can visit

http://definitelytyped.org/

and read [guides](http://definitelytyped.org/guides.html) for contributing or this [quick introduction](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files).

Summary:

- Essentially, it is necessary to create a `.d.ts` file which is then referenced by the special comment `/// <reference path="../path/to/file.d.ts" />` in your TypeScript script.
- Content of `.d.ts` files is typically written by hand. `lib.d.ts` was generated by a script but it is an exception. You can check some [projects that try to generate definition files](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/2103).
- A complete example of a definition file ([amplifyjs.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/amplifyjs/amplifyjs.d.ts)):

  ```
  // Type definitions for AmplifyJs 1.1.0
  // Project: http://amplifyjs.com/
  // Definitions by: Jonas Eriksson <https://github.com/joeriks/>
  // Definitions: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

  /// <reference path="../jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

  interface amplifyRequestSettings {
      resourceId: string;
      data?: any;
      success?: (...args: any[]) => void;
      error?: (...args: any[]) => void;
  }

  interface amplifyDecoder {
      (
          data?: any,
          status?: string,
          xhr?: JQueryXHR,
          success?: (...args: any[]) => void,
          error?: (...args: any[]) => void
      ): void
  }

  interface amplifyDecoders {
      [decoderName: string]: amplifyDecoder;
      jsSend: amplifyDecoder;
  }

  interface amplifyAjaxSettings extends JQueryAjaxSettings  {
      cache?: any;
      dataMap?: {} | ((data: any) => {});
      decoder?: any /* string or amplifyDecoder */;
  }

  interface amplifyRequest {

      /***
       * Request a resource.
       * resourceId: Identifier string for the resource.
       * data: A set of key/value pairs of data to be sent to the resource.
       * callback: A function to invoke if the resource is retrieved successfully.
       */
      (resourceId: string, hash?: any, callback?: Function): void;

      /***
       * Request a resource.
       * settings: A set of key/value pairs of settings for the request.
       *   resourceId: Identifier string for the resource.
       *   data (optional): Data associated with the request.
       *   success (optional): Function to invoke on success.
       *   error (optional): Function to invoke on error.
       */
      (settings: amplifyRequestSettings): any;

      /***
       * Define a resource.
       * resourceId: Identifier string for the resource.
       * requestType: The type of data retrieval method from the server. See the request types sections for more information.
       * settings: A set of key/value pairs that relate to the server communication technology. The following settings are available:
       *   Any settings found in jQuery.ajax().
       *   cache: See the cache section for more details.
       *   decoder: See the decoder section for more details.
       */
      define(resourceId: string, requestType: string, settings?: amplifyAjaxSettings): void;

      /***
       * Define a custom request.
       * resourceId: Identifier string for the resource.
       * resource: Function to handle requests. Receives a hash with the following properties:
       *   resourceId: Identifier string for the resource.
       *   data: Data provided by the user.
       *   success: Callback to invoke on success.
       *   error: Callback to invoke on error.
       */
      define(resourceId: string, resource: (settings: amplifyRequestSettings) => void): void;

      decoders: amplifyDecoders;
      cache: any;
  }

  interface amplifySubscribe {
      /***
       * Subscribe to a message.
       * topic: Name of the message to subscribe to.
       * callback: Function to invoke when the message is published.
       */
      (topic: string, callback: Function): void;
      /***
       * Subscribe to a message.
       * topic: Name of the message to subscribe to.
       * context: What this will be when the callback is invoked.
       * callback: Function to invoke when the message is published.
       * [priority]: Priority relative to other subscriptions for the same message. Lower values have higher priority. Default is 10.
       */
      (topic: string, context: any, callback: Function, priority?: number): void;
      /***
       * Subscribe to a message.
       * topic: Name of the message to subscribe to.
       * callback: Function to invoke when the message is published.
       * [priority]: Priority relative to other subscriptions for the same message. Lower values have higher priority. Default is 10.
       */
      (topic: string, callback: Function, priority?: number): void;
  }
  interface amplifyStorageTypeStore {
      /***
       * Stores a value for a given key using the default storage type.
       *
       * key: Identifier for the value being stored.
       * value: The value to store. The value can be anything that can be serialized as JSON.
       * [options]: A set of key/value pairs that relate to settings for storing the value.
       */
      (key: string, value: any, options?: any): void;

      /***
       * Gets a stored value based on the key.
       */
      (key: string): any;

      /***
       * Gets a hash of all stored values.
       */
      (): any;
  }

  interface amplifyStore extends amplifyStorageTypeStore{

      /***
       * IE 8+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 10.5+, iPhone 2+, Android 2+
       */
      localStorage: amplifyStorageTypeStore;

      /***
       * IE 8+, Firefox 2+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 10.5+, iPhone 2+, Android 2+
       */
      sessionStorage: amplifyStorageTypeStore;

      /***
       * Firefox 2+
       */
      globalStorage: amplifyStorageTypeStore;

      /***
       * IE 5 - 7
       */
      userData: amplifyStorageTypeStore;

      /***
       * An in-memory store is provided as a fallback if none of the other storage types are available.
       */
      memory: amplifyStorageTypeStore;


  }

  interface amplifyStatic {

      subscribe: amplifySubscribe;

      /***
       * Remove a subscription.
       * topic: The topic being unsubscribed from.
       * callback: The callback that was originally subscribed.
       */
      unsubscribe(topic: string, callback: Function): void;

      /***
       * Publish a message.
       * topic: The name of the message to publish.
       * Any additional parameters will be passed to the subscriptions.
       * amplify.publish returns a boolean indicating whether any subscriptions returned false. The return value is true if none of the subscriptions returned false, and false otherwise. Note that only one subscription can return false because doing so will prevent additional subscriptions from being invoked.
       */
      publish(topic: string, ...args: any[]): boolean;

      store: amplifyStore;

      request: amplifyRequest;

  }

  declare var amplify: amplifyStatic;
  ```